# Success message display for 5 seconds using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

i want to display the Success message for 5 seconds on click of submit button in ASP.net .
i want to achieve this using JQuery.
Please provide some guidelines.
If this question is answered then provide with the link.

Also, how to achieve this in MVC.

Comment: What is doing submit button? Post your data on server? Sync or async?

Comment: Post the data on server -@Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeOut(function(){
        //your code
    }, 5000); //or as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

so this is you posted:

*achieve this using JQuery*

You can use `.delay()` this way:

```
$('[type="submit"]').on('click', function () {
    $('#success').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
```

#### [jQuery Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sH44H/)

---

Although you can achieve it through plain js too:

```
document.getElementById('buttonid').onclick = function(){
      document.getElementById('successdiv').style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('successdiv').style.display = 'none';
      }, 5000);
};
```

#### [Pure js demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sH44H/1/)

---

### Note:

Be sure to hide the success div first and on click of your button show and then hide it after 5 seconds. so in the example 5 seconds is in miliseconds so `5sec == 5000 ms`.

Comment: Can you post some more detail, it is not working as i want. The label does not disappear.  - @Jai

Comment: @user43553 can you post your generated html code in your post.